# Type Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have had all sorts of bizarre errors, like the one in the title, happen when I am using the Android SDK and AVD Manager with Eclipse. Generally I just unplug the phone and plug it back in or close and reopen Eclipse but it is frustrating. Apparently `Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first` doesn't allow me to compile my app, i think it is because I was trying to run the emulator with some suggestions from [emulator is so slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1554099/708685) to no avail. thought i should add im running eclipse 3.5.2 on Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just restart the eclipse and run the project. The error arises while installing a new target version. After completion of the installation it will get fix automatically. Else restart eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

I met with the same error on my Macbook. I tried one of the methods explained at this link http://techmologies.blogspot.com/2009/05/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with_06.html and solved the problem.

Put the following 2 lines in the eclipse.ini file:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\bin\javaw.exe
```

Please modify the 2nd line according to the actual situation.

Comment: will that still work on linux? i honestly don't even know what folder eclipse is in, once i find it i will try your suggestion.

Comment: You can use the "find" command like this: find / -name eclipse

Comment: Worked for me after adding _...\jdk1.7.0\..._.

Answer (score 3):

If you have upgraded your SDK, and if you have not updated ADT plugin it will show this error. Please check it once by updating ADT plugin

Answer (score 2):

I made a new installation of Eclipse in different folder(with the same SDK folder) and imported the code to the workspace & it started to work again.