# Android error/warning Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first

Tags: android

I just started doing Android development today and I am getting this error message:

```
[2012-02-16 09:17:38 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first
```

and not sure if it requires some action on my part, or what ta heck it means :)

What should I do about it and what does it mean?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298790/type-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-wrapper-was-not